# bash if statement issue, cannot evaluate gt

Tags: bash, if-statement, scripting

Here is a part of my bash script. I want to track that the script is running.
so each time it runs the counter will increment, when the counter hits X (3 for my test) something will happen. I also want the count to reset.

The counter is incrementing,

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=( `cat "/home/pi/auto/mark"` )

three=3


if [ "$counter2" -gt "$three" ]; then
     echo 1 > /home/pi/auto/daycheck
```

Comment: You declare `counter` but use `counter2` in your check...

Comment: Also, in order to fill `counter`, use `$(cat /home/pi/auto/mark)`

Comment: Actually, use `$( < /home/pi/auto/mark)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming your `$counter2` is a typo

```
(( `</home/pi/auto/mark` > 3 )) && echo 1 > /home/pi/auto/daycheck
```